# Will Quadro M1200 GPU work with TensorFlow?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-quadro

m just starting out in deep learning and would like to try some small test models. I own a Quadro M1200 GPU (mobile version), with CUDA Compute capability 5.0. TensorFlow list of compatible Compute versions include 3.5 and 5.2, but doesn't explicitly list the 5.0. Is this GPU supported out of the box? Will I have to use an older version of TensorFlow, maybe build from sources?